# How to add a text file to a game so that it can track a person's score

Tags: c++

I have written a code that displays a rock-paper-scissors game against the computer. I would like to add a feature where I can create a text file in order to store the person's score and the computer score and keep track of the score but I don't know how to do it. Thank you in advance!

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

void rock_paper_scissors()
{
    static int userscore = 0;
    static int computerscore = 0;
    string playername;
    int userchoice;
    int computerchoice;


    

        cout << "Hello to rock-paper-scissors!\n";
        cout << "rock beats scissors, scissors beats paper and paper beats rock." << endl;
        cout << "choose 1 for rock, 2 for paper, 3 for scissors.\n";
        cout << "please enter your name." << endl;

        cin >> playername;
        cout << endl;

        cout << "Please enter your choice\n";
        cin >> userchoice;
        cout << endl;

        while (!(userchoice > 0 && userchoice <= 3))
        {
            cout << "invalid choice. please enter a number between 1 and 3\n";
            cin >> userchoice;
        }
            if (userchoice == 1)
            {
                cout << playername << " picked rock." << endl;
            }
            else if (userchoice == 2)
            {
                cout << playername << " picked paper." << endl;
            }
            else if (userchoice == 3)
            {
                cout << playername << " picked scissors." << endl;
            }
            
            
        


         computerchoice = (rand() % 3) + 1;
        if (userchoice == 1 && computerchoice == 3)
        {
            cout << playername  << " wins!" << endl;
        }
        else if (userchoice == 2 && computerchoice == 1)
        {
            cout << playername  << " wins!" << endl;
        }
        else if (userchoice == 3 && computerchoice == 2)
        {
            cout << playername  << " wins!" << endl;
        }
        else if (userchoice == computerchoice)
        {
            cout << " draw!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "computer wins!" << endl;
        }


        cout << "thank you for playing!\n";
        string restart;
        cout << "Would you like to play again?" << endl << "(y)es / (n)o" << endl;
        cin >> restart;
        if (restart == "y")
        {
            rock_paper_scissors();
        }









}

int main()
{
    cout << "MAIN\n";
    rock_paper_scissors();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to write the data into in file? Updating a simple txt file after each round could be cumbersome, as you always result in a single score at the end of the program. I would suggest changing the type of the `rock_paper_scissors` into `int` indicating the score achieved by the player in a single lot. The intermediate results are irrelevant. Just place the game loop into your main function and do not use a recursive function call and static function variables here. Otherwise, the player is forced to enter his name for every single lot.

Moreover, I tested your code and you have to change your error handling. I typed in "rock" and the program stuck in an infinity loop "invalid choice. please enter a number between 1 and 3\n" Whereby it is not possible to make another entry. As I entered a string instead of an integer, you have to reset the console. Beware of the dumbest possible user.

Moreover, you should seed your program to avoid identical computer choices in each game. This could be done with `srand(time(NULL))`.

Eventually, I write the tracked score into a score file at the end of the main function using the `fstream` standard library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>    // min max
#include <fstream>      // read/write from/to files
#include <time.h>       // time


using namespace std;

int rock_paper_scissors(const std::string& playername);


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    cout << "MAIN\n";
    cout << "Hello to rock-paper-scissors!\n";
    cout << "rock beats scissors, scissors beats paper and paper beats rock." << endl;
    cout << "choose 1 for rock, 2 for paper, 3 for scissors.\n";


    int userscore = 0;
    int computerscore = 0;
    std::string playername;
    std::string restart;

    cout << "please enter your name." << endl;
    cin >> playername;
    cout << endl;

    do
    {
        int result = rock_paper_scissors(playername);
        cout << "thank you for playing!\n";
        
        userscore += result;
        computerscore += std::max(0, 3 - 2 * result);
        
        cout << playername << "'s score: " << userscore;
        cout << "\ncomputer's score: " << computerscore;

        cout << "\nWould you like to play again?" << endl << "(y)es / (n)o" << endl;
        cin >> restart;

    } while (restart == "y");


    std::ofstream ofile;
    ofile.open("scorefile.txt");

    ofile << "Scores:\n" << playername << ": " << userscore;
    ofile << "\nComputer: " << computerscore;

    ofile.close();

    return 0;
}


int rock_paper_scissors(const std::string& playername)
{
    int userchoice;
    int computerchoice;

    cout << endl << endl;

    do {
        cout << "Please enter your choice\n";
        if (std::cin >> userchoice)
        {
            if (userchoice > 0 && userchoice <= 3)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "invalid choice. please enter a number between 1 and 3\n";
                continue;
            }
        }
        else if (!cin.bad() && !cin.eof())
        {
            // a non integer value entered
            cerr << "invalid choice. please enter a number between 1 and 3\n";
            // Reset error state
            cin.clear();
            // remove error input
            cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    } while (true);

    if (userchoice == 1)
    {
        cout << playername << " picked rock." << endl;
    }
    else if (userchoice == 2)
    {
        cout << playername << " picked paper." << endl;
    }
    else if (userchoice == 3)
    {
        cout << playername << " picked scissors." << endl;
    }



    computerchoice = (rand() % 3) + 1;
    if (userchoice == 1 && computerchoice == 3)
    {
        cout << playername << " wins!" << endl;
        return 3;
    }
    else if (userchoice == 2 && computerchoice == 1)
    {
        cout << playername << " wins!" << endl;
        return 3;
    }
    else if (userchoice == 3 && computerchoice == 2)
    {
        cout << playername << " wins!" << endl;
        return 3;
    }
    else if (userchoice == computerchoice)
    {
        cout << " draw!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "computer wins!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the explanations. I simply have to store the scores in a file because it is part of the assignment that I'm doing.

Comment: This is reason enough :)

Comment: If you need the score of every single lot, create and open the output file stream ofile before the do-while loop of the main function. After each call of rock_paper_scissors you can write the result of the game into the file. If my answer is correct, please consider an upvote.